# Showing custom column info in a document set on folders

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-enterprise, document-library, document-set

I have a library that is a document library for tenders in sales.

Each tender is created as a new document sewith set of custom columns (tender number, customer, status etc) and these are being displayed and all of the documenta inherit the document set properties.

Is it possible to make the folders inside to inherit the document set properties like the documents and also show this ?

Or is this only possible on documents since its called document set and not folder set?

Answer (score 0):

Per my test, first, set custom columns as shared columns, when you create a new folder in the document set, click quick edit in the ribbon, enter a number arbitrarily then click save, it will inherit the document set's properties.